How to setup sortable and droppable at the same time using React DnD kit
I have rows of categories, in a table like view, i want these categories to be droppable as i will be dragging items and adding them, at the same time i want the categories to be sortable, but using this, the transform variable is being returned as undefined, if i remove the droppable it works perfectly fine and i can animate the sorting, the functionality is working onDragEnd, but i can't see while i am sorting.
const DroppableCategoryRow = ({
  id,
  name,
  items,
  isOpen,
  onRowClick,
}: Props) => {
  const { isOver, setNodeRef: setDroppableNodeRef } = useDroppable({
    id: `droppableCategory-${id}`,
  });

  const {
    attributes,
    listeners,
    setNodeRef: setSortableNodeRef,
    transform,
    transition,
    isDragging,
  } = useSortable({
    id: `sortableCategory-${id}`,
  });

  console.log('transofrm', transform);
  const style = {
    transform: transform ? CSS.Transform.toString(transform) : undefined,
    transition: transition, // default transition for smooth animation
  };

  return (
    <div ref={setSortableNodeRef} style={style} {...attributes}>
      <div className='w-full' ref={setDroppableNodeRef}>
        {/* header row */}
        <CategoryTableRow
          id={id}
          isOpen={isOpen}
          itemsCount={items.length}
          name={name}
          onRowClick={onRowClick}
          listeners={listeners}
        />
        {/* accordion open */}
        <div
          className={cn(
            'grid grid-rows-[0fr] transition-[grid-template-rows] duration-300',
            {
              'grid-rows-[1fr]': isOpen,
            }
          )}
        >
          <SortableContext
            // id is the category id , as the category can have multiple items with same id, so we need to uniquely identify themn
            items={items.map((item) => `sortableItem-${item.id}-${id}`)}
            strategy={verticalListSortingStrategy}
          >
            <div className='overflow-hidden pl-10'>
              {items.map((item, idx) => (
                <ItemTableRow
                  key={idx}
                  name={item.name}
                  id={item.id}
                  currency={'LBP'}
                  price={5000}
                  categoryId={id}
                  categoryName={name}
                />
              ))}
            </div>
          </SortableContext>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

I tried setting the 2 ref nodes to the same div
I tried setting to 2 seperate divs, it still doesn't work
any help is greatly appreciated!
